# top 7 problems for artists

Tags: sound-design

A client/partner has posed the question to me, I suppose as some sort of test,
"can you tell me what the top 7 problems artists and producers have with studios and sound engeers and how you solve them". I am not sure at all how to answer this. Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

> can you tell me what the top 7 problems artists and producers have
>   with studios and sound engeers and how you solve them

You will have to define a couple of things:

- "artists" -- you will have to define what this means: does this mean proffessional recording musicians, single musicians, bands, orchestra's. You will have to define if this is popular music, rock, classical, vocals or maybe a mix of all. Do you include amateurs, partime musicians? -- you need to define your sample group.
- "producers" -- define what is a "producer" same as above
- "sample group" -- next to define is what would be your sample group, is a 100 samples enough, would you need a 1000 samples to get an relevant output.
- "demographic" -- do you want to concentrate on a particular region, or country, or would it be international?

Once you figure out what you are really asking, you need to get the cooperation of these people and question them. Use both closed questions as well as open questions.

With the data/sample at hand, you will need to analyze the data, and formulate your "top-7 problems".

Once you have "top-7 problems" you will have to get cooperation of the same sample group and question them how they perceive these problems have been solved for them in the past. This is only a perception, so your data will have to be cross referenced with data of your second sample group.

Your second sample group should be of studio-engineers, which you question on how would they solve the top-7 problems given from your first data set.

This data, will have to be cross referenced by the data from the first sample group on how they perceived the problems were solved, and you will find that each item in your top-7-problems would have multiple solutions for each.

Finally you will have to determine that for each of the top-7-problems what would be the most fitting solution from the second data set. Or maybe you will need a top-7-solutions for each of the top-7-problems, giving you a total of 49 answers.

All this will need to solid statistical and mathematical base, so I would certainly get involvement of a data scientist with experience in this.

Good Luck!